# why does the number 51444.325061 doesnot round off to 51444.325 upto 3 decimal places? I want to round off this number in c programming

Tags: c, floating-point, decimal, rounding, precision

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    float n;
    scanf("%f", &n);
    printf("%.3f", n);
}
```

input: `51444.325061`

my output: `51444.324`

expected output: `51444.325`

**why does I dont get the proper answer?**

Comment: How many bits does a float have?

Comment: Try using a `double`.  A `float` only has about 7 digits' worth of precision -- and that's *all* digits, not just digits after the decimal point.  So `51444.32` is all you get, and everything after that is suspect.  (It's more complicated than that, actually, which is why I said "about 7" and not "exactly 7" -- because it's not exactly 7.)

Comment: If you change to `double`, you'll also have to change to `scanf("%lf",&n);`.

Comment: Unrelated to the question: But always check the return value of `scanf()`, you code causes UB when `scanf()` fails, which happens when the input is not a number and in some other cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

32-bit `float` can encode  about 2<sup>32</sup> different values.

`51444.325061`is not one of them<sup>**</sup>.  Instead the nearest `float` is exactly 51444.32421875.  The next best choice would be 51444.328125.

Printing 51444.32421875 to 3 decimal places is best as "51444.324".

---

> why does I dont get the proper answer?

`float` is too imprecise to encode 51444.325061 as OP desires.  Using `double` will help.  The same problem exists, yet only appears when about 16+ significant digits are needed.

---

<sup>**</sup> Encodable finite values are of the form: some_integer * 2<sup>some_exponent</sup>.

Comment: IIRC, it is 2\*\*23*(2\*\*9-2) (-1 if you don't count -0 and +0 as different values) different values.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 Looks  right for IEEE.

Answer (score 1):

Internally, floating-point numbers are not represented as decimal fractions, as you might expect.  Instead, they use a floating-point representation based on *binary* (base-2) numbers.

Because they're base-2, these floating-point numbers cannot represent decimal fractions exactly.

Here are the available `float` values nearest to 51444.325061, along with their exact decimal equivalents:

```
0x4748f452  51444.32031250  0.784978032112121582031250 × 2^16
0x4748f453  51444.32421875  0.784978091716766357421875 × 2^16
0x4748f454  51444.32812500  0.784978151321411132812500 × 2^16
0x4748f455  51444.33203125  0.784978210926055908203125 × 2^16
```

So you can take your pick between 51444.324 or 51444.328.  But obviously 51444.324 is closer.

Comment: thankyou everyone by changing float to double i got the answer correct